# Script con ciclo While muy lento SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Actualmente tengo un script el cual extraigo información de otro servidor AS400 mediante OPENQUERY, el script funciona perfecto, sin embargo tarda alrededor de 11 minutos en generar, tiempo que quisiera mejorar

comparto script

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Cliente') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Cliente
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Cliente (
Codigo INT,
Nombre VARCHAR(400),
Identidad VARCHAR(30)
)


;WITH cte_Cliente AS (
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.NumeroDocumento) Orden
,c.*
FROM dbo.Informacion1 c
)


SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM cte_Cliente ct


DECLARE @Contador INT = 1
DECLARE @Registros INT = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.NumeroDocumento) FROM #Temp c)
DECLARE @Identidad VARCHAR(30)


WHILE (@Registros>0 AND @Contador<=@Registros)
BEGIN

SELECT @Identidad = (SELECT t.NumeroDocumento FROM #Temp t WHERE t.Orden = @Contador )

DECLARE @ClienteColector VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ClienteColector = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(IBSREPLICA,''
SELECT
 CU.Code
,CU.Name
,CU.identific
FROM BRUCYFILES.CLIENTE CU
WHERE CU.CUSIDN = '''''+CONVERT(CHAR(30),@Identidad)+'''''
'')
'

INSERT INTO #Cliente_Colector
EXEC(@ClienteColector)

SET @Contador = @Contador + 1

END 

SELECT * FROM #Cliente_Colector
```

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar planes de ejecución en SQL Server, con eso puedes tener un mejor entendimiento de cómo se comportan tus querys y si existe algún cuello de botella

Comment: Saludos. Prueba lo siguiente; ya que tu columna `CU.CUSIDN` (al parecer) es la única condición; en vez de realizar el `INSERT` por la cantidad de `@Registros`; concatena un texto con los `CONVERT(CHAR(30),@Identidad)` (de forma correcta) para que en lugar de `WHERE CU.CUSIDN =` **`"UN_CUSIDN" `** en relación a un solo valor de `@Identidad` *sea* `WHERE CU.CUSIDN` **`IN ("UN_CUSIDN1",..., "UN_CUSIDN_N")`**; con los cambios que correspondan a primero obtener el string para el **IN** y ya con ello ejecutar **INSERT** haciendo solo una llamada

Comment: Lo ideal sería usar un cursor `LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY` para no tener que leer la tabla cada vez. Pero es probable que el problema sea el estar tomando los datos usando OPENQUERY y esa consulta puede ser lo que se tome la mayor parte del tiempo.